# Perl - passing argument to push function by value

Tags: perl

```
push (@{$processor{$-[0]}}, $metadata[$_]{"formatters"});
foreach my $key (keys @{$metadata[$_]{"formatters"}}) {
    $metadata[$_]{"formatters"}[$key]{"scope"} = "end";
}
push (@{$processor{$+[0]}}, $metadata[$_]{"formatters"});
```

I push `$metadata[$_]{"formatters"}` into `@{$processor{$-[0]}}`. 
Then i need change something and push it again, but these changes are reflected too where i push first. Seems like i am passing this `$metadata[$_]{"formatters"}` by reference and not by value, but i can`t find, how to pass it by value.

Comment: Yea it's a "feature" of perl. Don't repush the value. If you modify a value index in a for loop of an array it modifies the array itself.

Comment: @scrappedcola: thx, i go check it

Comment: @scrappedcola: That isn't the problem. And what you describe is a feature of pretty much every language ever.

Comment: All you duplicate voters, this *is not the same problem*. The code correctly modifies every item of an array, but the change is appearing elsewhere because, as the OP correctly says, a reference to the modified data is stored in two places.

Comment: SO got so many good features from PM, shame they didn't get *keep* votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `$metadata[$_]{'formatters'}` is itself a complex datastructure, it doesn't have a "value" per se.  You can push a copy of it, though.

To just make a shallow copy (probably not what you want, since the new array will still have references to all the same hashes):

```
$orig = $metadata[$_]{'formatters'};
$copy = [ @$orig ];
```

To copy each referred-to hash also:

```
$orig = $metadata[$_]{'formatters'};
$copy = [ map +{%$_}, @$orig ];
```

Or to just copy any arbitrary datastructure:

```
$copy = Storable::dclone($orig);
```

(There are various Clone modules on CPAN that also do this.)

Answer (score 1):

I am very worried about your design. A structure like

```
$metadata[$_]{formatters}[$key]{scope}
```

is complex, and it seems you have multiple copies of very similar data.

However, the problem is that `$metadata[$_]{formatters}` is a *reference* to an array of hashes. Wherever you put that reference it will refer to the same data, so modifying it will be reflected in any reference to it.

You need to copy your array of hashes to an identical data structure before modifying it, and you can do that using this code. I have a suspicion that the array is a sparse one (i.e. that not all of its elements contain data) and have coded accordingly. If I am wrong, and every element is a hash reference, then you can simplify this to `my $copy = [ map { {%$_} } @$formatters ]`.

```
my $formatters = $metadata[$_]{formatters};

{
  my $copy = [ map $_ ? {%$_} : undef, @$formatters ];
  push @{$processor{$-[0]}}, $copy;

  for my $key (0 .. $#$copy) {
    $copy->[$key]{scope} = 'end';
  }
}

{
  my $copy = [ map $_ ? {%$_} : undef, @$formatters ];
  push @{$processor{$+[0]}}, $copy;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code won't even compile.
You are calling keys on @{$metadata[$_]{"formatters"}}
which is not a hash, it's an Array.

The question is ill-formed.

This code is incredibly convoluted and hard to understand.
I strongly recommend using the -> notation when nesting
structures like this to make it clear that you are using references
to substructures.

To deep-copy a structure so that you don't end up getting
references to subcomponents, I would suggest cloning.  e.g.:


`use Clone qw(clone);
push (@{$processor{$-[0]}}, clone($metadata[$_]{"formatters"}));`

Comment: Actually, keys can be called on arrays since 5.12. It returns the keys (aka indexes) of the elements of the array. `0..$#{$metadata[$_]{"formatters"}}` would be the backwards compatible alternative.

Comment: Adding unnecessary `->` is generally viewed as a *hinderence* to readability.

Comment: (I didn't -1, though. The solution you presented is fine.)